# Is there a way to apply euphoria physics (ragdoll) to rigged Sprites in Unity2D?

Tags: c#, 2d, sprites, unity

With euphoria physics I mean the realistic object interaction and freefall as seen in most games like recent GTAs. But I want to do that in 2D. (I am a beginner :P).

Comment: I don't know of any middleware for it, though it should be possible to make something like that, it will be really difficult. Being a beginner you might wanna skip that for now =p

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden Lol, good idea